# Extract Data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from a stock exchange website using BeautifulSoup but I'm getting only the column names as a result. Here is the code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/saudiexchange/newsandreports/reports-publications/historical-reports/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8ziTR3NDIw8LAz8DTxCnA3MDILdzUJDLAyNXE30I4EKzHEqMDTTDyekoCA7zRMAIkY09Q!!/'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table1 = soup.find('div', id='tab1Content')

headers = []
for i in table1.find_all('th'):
  title = i.text
  headers.append(title)

  mydata = pd.DataFrame(columns = headers)

for j in table1.find_all('tr')[1:]:
  row_data = j.find_all('td')
  row = [i.text for i in row_data]
  length = len(mydata)
  mydata.loc[length] = row

mydata
```

Can anyone please help me find a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if you received data or not? And which data? Try putting one `print` in the code, and print the row data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is present on a page inside a script tag not in the HTML as you're trying in the code, and the data from script tag is rendered to the HTML as the page is loaded.

I updated the code as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.saudiexchange.sa/wps/portal/saudiexchange/newsandreports/reports-publications/historical-reports/!ut/p/z1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfIjo8ziTR3NDIw8LAz8DTxCnA3MDILdzUJDLAyNXE30I4EKzHEqMDTTDyekoCA7zRMAIkY09Q!!/'

page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
records = re.findall('JSON\.stringify.*(\[.*\])', page.find_all('script', {'type': 'text/javascript'})[-3].text)
if records:
    records = json.loads(records[0])

df = pandas.DataFrame(records)

print(df)
```

Upon loading the page into `BeautifulSoup`, I am fetching the exact tag, then used a regular expression to find the line which has the entire data as JSON, loaded JSON into a dictionary, and then loaded it to a DataFrame.

Output:

```
   transactionDate volumeTraded          turnOver todaysOpen  highPrice   lowPrice previousClosePrice noOfTrades change changePercent lastTradePrice transactionDateStr lastYield
0       2023/07/27  234,061,315  6,479,159,448.07  11,894.32  11,933.68  11,847.72          11,847.72    395,910   None          None           None         2023/07/27      None
1       2023/07/26  250,527,031  6,587,353,138.03  11,892.58  11,917.29  11,848.73          11,906.13    401,644   None          None           None         2023/07/26      None
2       2023/07/25  242,896,126  6,747,776,834.91  11,842.11  11,896.87  11,834.82          11,882.68    404,113   None          None           None         2023/07/25      None
3       2023/07/24  272,729,851  6,299,890,410.07  11,761.42  11,819.51  11,740.82          11,801.90    401,279   None          None           None         2023/07/24      None
4       2023/07/23  167,268,795  4,259,359,309.53  11,757.07  11,773.25  11,715.77          11,760.30    320,118   None          None           None         2023/07/23      None
5       2023/07/20  245,817,586  5,825,981,456.79  11,767.83  11,775.56  11,723.65          11,755.94    387,269   None          None           None         2023/07/20      None
6       2023/07/19  254,172,064  5,562,000,894.80  11,768.50  11,786.26  11,733.82          11,752.63    386,933   None          None           None         2023/07/19      None
7       2023/07/18  326,862,994  8,108,296,076.36  11,794.96  11,826.34  11,726.76          11,768.71    512,443   None          None           None         2023/07/18      None
8       2023/07/17  274,100,305  8,110,774,890.18  11,713.39  11,784.99  11,671.15          11,780.27    503,442   None          None           None         2023/07/17      None
9       2023/07/16  275,812,887  6,752,825,160.20  11,733.20  11,754.37  11,694.07          11,715.50    430,684   None          None           None         2023/07/16      None
10      2023/07/13  410,661,272  7,696,321,347.04  11,740.65  11,750.37  11,695.62          11,707.87    465,247   None          None           None         2023/07/13      None
11      2023/07/12  444,684,118  7,803,773,389.44  11,685.53  11,758.79  11,678.72          11,727.19    463,712   None          None           None         2023/07/12      None
12      2023/07/11  354,779,942  7,756,051,185.86  11,604.16  11,673.27  11,603.25          11,664.50    494,277   None          None           None         2023/07/11      None
13      2023/07/10  472,639,436  6,881,526,719.26  11,594.38  11,624.22  11,565.82          11,586.93    478,975   None          None           None         2023/07/10      None
14      2023/07/09  317,880,581  6,035,872,429.64  11,590.76  11,618.03  11,557.67          11,609.35    407,213   None          None           None         2023/07/09      None
15      2023/07/06  313,606,717  6,576,334,138.08  11,596.00  11,598.61  11,553.97          11,597.91    445,013   None          None           None         2023/07/06      None
16      2023/07/05  304,527,392  8,489,250,022.12  11,615.91  11,637.41  11,568.00          11,591.55    528,784   None          None           None         2023/07/05      None
17      2023/07/04  433,117,492  7,255,962,416.93  11,557.80  11,618.72  11,552.60          11,618.72    461,782   None          None           None         2023/07/04      None
18      2023/07/03  478,324,863  7,123,786,536.34  11,508.35  11,545.13  11,463.83          11,545.13    510,590   None          None           None         2023/07/03      None
19      2023/07/02  336,148,365  4,566,009,523.79  11,491.76  11,522.87  11,481.73          11,493.91    336,150   None          None           None         2023/07/02      None
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and clarification @Zero! I really appreciate it. The website allows us to choose the stock (In my case, Market/Indices = Main Market, Select Sector = Banks and Select Entity = Riyad Bank) as well as the time period (In my case, from 01-01-2004 to 01-01-2023). Is there a way to get such data using BeautifulSoup? I really apologize for the inconvenience.